# How can I make my function execute even when no parameter is entered?

Tags: php, function, arguments, switch-statement

I'm teaching myself PHP through a book and to make this easier I made myself a function to save myself having to write `echo "<br/>";` a million times. My function works fine but after accidentally leaving out a parameter and getting an error I tried to make it so that if I left the function empty it would simply add one `<br/>` but I can't seem to get it to work.

Here is my code after my last attempt (which was to try `case NULL: echo "<br/>";`):

```
function br($break){
    switch ($break){
        case 1:
            echo "<br/>";
            break;
        case 2:
            echo "<br/><br/>";
            break;
        case 3:
            echo "<br/><br/><br/>";
            break;
        case 4:
            echo "<br/><br/><br/><br/>";
            break;
        case 5:
            echo "<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>";
            break;
        case NULL:
            echo "<br/>";
    }

}
```

Any ideas? Thanks guys!

P.s. Sorry if this is a really silly question, I only started learning PHP on Monday and my programming experience is somewhat limited :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
function br($break = 1){

}
```

Btw, for your case, you can actually use:

```
echo str_repeat('<br />', 5);
```

Which will create 5 br's, take a look here: http://php.net/str_repeat
Also, when you are in doubt for something, first time check php.net documentation, there might be a function that does what you want already.

Answer (score 1):

If yopu want 1 br by default, You can do this:

```
function br($break = 1){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is probably easier to not use switch at all and instead do something like this perhaps:

```
function br($break = null)
{
    if(!is_null($break)) {
        echo str_repeat('<br />', (int) $break);
    } else {
        echo '<br />';
    }
}
```

(not tested)